# AWS SDK C++ issue in Linux while in Windows it works fine

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services

In windows, I am using VS2017 and through NuGet manager I added AWS Kinesis C++ SDK in my project.
The build works perfectly fine in windows.

I commit the same code in SVN and while trying to build in Linux which is having GCC 4.9.2, 
the build fails with below mentioned error.

libwebql.so is part of my already existing project in which I added AWS code which works/build fine in windows but not in linux. 
Anything different has to be done related to build or inclusion of aws code?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
webql/control/cl: Linking release binary webql
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::InitAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const &)'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Http::CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Malloc(char const *, unsigned long)'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Kinesis::KinesisClient::PutRecord(Aws::Kinesis::Model::PutRecordRequest const &) const'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to `Aws::Free(void *)'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest::GetBody() const'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::ShutdownAPI(Aws::SDKOptions const &)'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `typeinfo for Aws::AmazonSerializableWebServiceRequest'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `vtable for Aws::Kinesis::Model::PutRecordRequest'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration::ClientConfiguration()'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Kinesis::KinesisClient::~KinesisClient()'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Kinesis::KinesisClient::KinesisClient(Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration const &)'
/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/bin/libwebql.so: undefined reference to
   `Aws::Kinesis::Model::PutRecordRequest::PutRecordRequest()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Command for compilation and build** This is only for reference.
My solution have 24 projects where 2 projects uses this AWS C++ SDK, which works fine in windows but not in linux.

general: @/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/gfilt -pthread -fPIC -DHAS_SETRESUID_PROTO=1 -DHAS_SETRESGID_PROTO=1 -DU_HAVE_NAMESPACE=1 
-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_unix -D_BSD -fexceptions -fmessage-length=0 -DQL2_PLATFORM="al" -DJAVA_ARCH="amd64" -fvisibility=hidden -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 
-DGENERAL_EXPORTS -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/include -I. 
-I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxml 
-I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxslt -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/include 
-I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/zlib -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include 
-I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include/linux -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux 
-I/mnt/usr/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/include/nspr -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/include/js 
-I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/js/src -ggdb3 -O3 -DNDEBUG -c -o /archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/obj/general/Constructs.o Constructs.cxx

Comment: How do you build your application, more specifically how do you *link* your application on the Linux side? It seems that the `webql` library have some dependencies that you don't link with, or link with *in the wrong order*. On Linux you need to link in a specific order: If library A depends on library B, then you need to link them in that specific order: `-lA -lB`.

Comment: **Some programmer dude** :-) we already have standard build process which does so.
As an enhancement i added AWS C++ SDK which download related package and change minor project settings (which can be seen during commit). Now when i build it in windows using vs 2017 it works prettly well. 
My expectation is that in linux the code compilation should happen as it is happening in windows.

Comment: general: @/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/gfilt -pthread -fPIC -DHAS_SETRESUID_PROTO=1 -DHAS_SETRESGID_PROTO=1 -DU_HAVE_NAMESPACE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_unix -D_BSD -fexceptions -fmessage-length=0 -DQL2_PLATFORM="al" -DJAVA_ARCH="amd64" -fvisibility=hidden -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -DGENERAL_EXPORTS -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/general/include -I. -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxml -

Comment: I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/xml/libxslt -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dev/zlib -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/inst/jdk/include/linux -I/usr/java/include -I/usr/java/include/linux -I/mnt/usr/include -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/include/nspr -I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/include/js -

Comment: I/archive/webql/build/al/current/base/packages/al/mozilla/js/src -ggdb3 -O3 -DNDEBUG -c -o /archive/webql/build/al/current/base/dist/alr/obj/general/Constructs.o Constructs.cxx

The above 3 comments are the part of build command.

Comment: Please ***[edit]*** your question to include this information.